# Adding a column after another column within SQL

Tags: sql

How do I add a column after another column within MS SQL by using SQL query?

TempTable
   ID int,
   Type nvarchar(20),
   Active bit

NewTable
   ID int,
   Type nvarchar(20),
   Description text,
   Active bit

That is what I want, how do I do that

Comment: Column order is irrelevant to SQL.  You can define column order in SELECT, INSERT or UPDATE statements.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I just like things structured a certain way

Comment: since column **order** really isn't relevant, there's no such feature in SQL Server / T-SQL. You need to either use the interactive table designer (which will re-create the entire table in the process), or you just have to let it be.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Add a column to the end of the table:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD myNewColumn VARCHAR(255);
```

Add a column to the start of the table:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD myNewColumn VARCHAR(255) FIRST;
```

Add a column after an existing column:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD myNewColumn VARCHAR(255) AFTER myOtherColumn;
```

For additional options, see [MySQL's ALTER TABLE documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: this is MS SQL not MySQL unfortunately

Comment: In that case, I believe you have to recreate the entire table. Why does column order matter?

Comment: I am just really picky like that, and prefer tables to have a certain order. Ok I will just have to recreate it

Comment: Heh, fair enough. Maybe add the column, then add copies of the columns that you want to be after the added column, update the column values, drop old columns and rename the new. A pain, but necessary.

Comment: I tried it on MYSQL and it worked for me. Server: MySQL Version: 5.5.29 Engine InnoDB.

Comment: This doesn't work for mySQL 5.6.21-69.0-log
It should be "ADD COLUMN" instead of "ADD" for starters. Also "AFTER" throws an error

Comment: How to make that new column first in the table

Comment: this still isn't mysql, but the answer still says it is.

Comment: is it possible to add a column after a particular column in PostgreSQL using pgAdmin

Answer (score 9):

It depends on what database you are using. In MySQL, you would use the "ALTER TABLE" syntax. I don't remember exactly how, but it would go something like this if you wanted to add a column called 'newcol' that was a 200 character varchar:

```
ALTER TABLE example ADD newCol VARCHAR(200) AFTER otherCol;
```

Answer (score 2):

In a Firebird database the `AFTER myOtherColumn` does not work but you can try re-positioning the column using:

```
ALTER TABLE name ALTER column POSITION new_position
```

I guess it may work in other cases as well.